# sql query working mechnism

Tags: mysql

I write a query from internet to retrieve name,salary and department no who earn a salary greater than the average salary of their department.The query is

```
SELECT name,salary,dno
From employee e
where salary>(select avg(salary) from employee e1 where e1.dno=e.dno);
```

This give me the desired result.

My question is why there is no error like subquery returns more than one row  as in my query subquery returns multiple value

Comment: Why would the subquery return more than one row? There is no group by clause. avg function will summarise the whole thing into one single value

Comment: Why is this tagged both MySQL and SQL Server?

Comment: Try running your subquery as it's own query and you'll that it has only a single row, regardless of the WHERE statement.